# Need a Non-Scrolling Grid on top of a Canvas inside of a ScrollViewer in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

***The code below is fine, the issue was elsewhere - leaving here incase others need the info.**

I am creating a simulator that has a large scrollable-zoomable `Canvas`. I need to be to place a `StackPanel` (or whatever) on top of this canvas, but it should not scroll or zoom. This is what I've got:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Label Content="{Binding Date, StringFormat=Date: {0}}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding CO2Level}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding O2Level}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding H2OLevels}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding TempC}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding TempF}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding SolarLevels}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Grid Name="grid" Width="65535" Height="65535" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Width="0" Height="0" RenderTransform="1 0 0 -1 0 0">
                <!-- Setup automatic viewing of Lifeforms -->
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Entities}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Path Data="{Binding Geometry}"
                            Fill="{Binding Fill}"
                            StrokeThickness="0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

However it is not working, the lebels do not show up at all and I cannot figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Place both the `ScrollViewer` and the `StackPanel` in a panel that allows its children to overlap, such as a `Grid` or a `Canvas`

Comment: @Rachel - thanks, that is what I have been doing. I adjusted the question to show the complete display code.

Comment: Actually, after further testing it looks like my code is sound, but I have an issue with my bound data.  Leaving this up in case others need the code example.

Comment: It's probably just that your `Label.Content`s are null or empty.